# Differences between createObject and createManagedObject

Tags: silverlight

I'm using [HtmlPage.RegisterCreateableType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmlpage.registercreateabletype%28VS.95%29.aspx) method to call some C# code from javascript. In MSDN documentation they say:

> Registers a managed type as available for creation from JavaScript
>   code, through the **Content.services.createObject** and
>   **Content.services.createManagedObject** helper methods

There isn't more explanation about these two methods and I don't know what are the differences. Anybody knows differences between these methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tons of information on both of these methods here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645087%28VS.95%29.aspx).

> **createObject**
>   Description: Given a registered scriptAlias, this method returns a
>   script wrapper for the corresponding managed type.
>
> **createManagedObject** 
>   Description: Given the typeName of the target .NET Framework type,
>   this method creates a default instance of the type by using either a
>   parameterless constructor (for reference types) or the default value
>   representation (for value types).

Basically, you use createObject if you have a [script alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.scriptablememberattribute.scriptalias%28VS.95%29.aspx) to an object. If you just need to create an instance of a type of object you use createManagedObject.